# Using rsh in a shell script

Tags: powershell, openshift

As part of a powershell script im working on, i use rsh in order to connect to another shell however after using this all subsequent commands are ignored and the script just ends.

My workflow is:

- rsh "podname"
- cd "path"
- exit

Everything after I use rsh is ignored. Is there a way to get the script to wait until the rsh is completed?

Using: oc rsh foo "cd /path && somecommand" resulted in an error saying that no such directory existed. Is this because it's trying to find /path on the local machine and not the remote one?

Comment: Having the relevant parts of your script would help, can you add those to the question?

Comment: Just did, there isn't much in the script after rsh

Answer (score 0):

When you just run `oc rsh`, that is an interactive command that might interfere with your script. So when running a command inside a container, you should add the commands as an argument to the `oc rsh` command, here is an example:

```
# Run the command 'cat /etc/resolv.conf' inside pod 'foo'
oc rsh foo cat /etc/resolv.conf
```

So in your case something like the following could help in your case:

```
oc rsh foo "cd /path && somecommand"
```

Comment: When I did: 

oc rsh foo "cd /path && exit"

It gave me the following error: starting container process caused "exec: \"cd /path && exit\": stat cd / path && exit: no such file or directory.